# possible to automate the ADFS SAML SSO MFA authenticator app code on a mobile app SSO flow?

Tags: azure, mobile, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I have a properly authenticating SAML service working with ADFS. When we switch on MFA - the SSO flow requests an access code from an Authenticator app. The only way this seems to work on a mobile device is to break out of the SSO app and go to the Authenticator app to retrieve a new code. Then the user has to return to the mobile app and manually punch it in. Is there an automation step or config setting somewhere that might make this flow more user friendly by automating the auth step within the existing SAML flow instead of having to break out of the app to retrieve the code ?

Answer (score 0):

•   Since, you have configured SAML SSO for ADFS with MFA, and selected **‘Microsoft Authenticator’** app as second factor authentication medium, in this process, you will have to enter the one-time passcode appearing in the app for 30 seconds in the authenticator app in the MFA authentication window. So, ***since this is not unlike OTP (One Time Passcode) which is received as a text message in your cell phone upon requesting for login through ADFS. As if it was a text message, it could be naturally copied by giving the app access to read text messages permission in ‘Apps and permissions’ section of the cell phone if it was Android***. Similarly, `I would suggest you to please give your app permission to read the data from Microsoft Authenticator app in your cell phone settings and accordingly test it`.

•   But as far as I know, **your app may not have the configuration settings to do so as Microsoft Authenticator app is just an application that is installed from ‘Playstore’ unlike any other system app like text message, inbuilt app notification, etc.** Thus, I would like to suggest **you to please enable the setting ‘Draw over other apps’ for your app which requires authentication through ADFS for the Microsoft Authenticator app by modifying the ‘AndroidAppManifest.xml’ file which will make it possible to read the ‘One-time passcode’ generated in the Microsoft authenticator app and in effect will automate the two-factor authentication for your app login through ADFS.**

Kindly refer to the link below for more information on modifying the **‘AndroidAppManifest.xml’** file: -

**[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20draw%20over,android.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20draw%20over,android.)**

Also, find the link below which states the configuration that needs to be done for enabling the Azure MFA as well as various prerequisites needed for that purpose: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-and-azure-mfa**

Comment: So i'm frankly not sure if this answer should be accepted or not because in researching this issue i ran across the MSAL library which looks like is the "proper" way to implement the MFA flow for mobile on SSO for ADFS by using the Authenticator and not trying to wire this via a browser component. SO in effect i'm not pursuing this answer path so i cant confirm it is a good answer. Reads like it is ?

Comment: I provided the answer with the intention that you want to retrieve the 'App access code' from the authenticator app automatically even when logging into the SaaS app through your mobile application without logging into the authenticator app and directly getting it from there and suggesting it in the mobile app similar to the OTP received in the text message.